# Use the windows 10 shutdown message in c#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10

Is there a way to use the message shown on windows 10 that shows when executing `shutdown.exe -c "something"` in my own way?

The message window built into windows 10:
[image: Windows built-in shutdown message box]

What I want to do is use this type of built-in message and call it from my C# application, containing other information where I want to edit the title and description text. Is this at all possible?

**EDIT:**

To clarify: I don't want to shutdown the system. I only want to utilize the message for other purposes, without shutting down at all!

Comment: Do you also need the dialog to darken the rest of the screen and can only be dismissed by clicking Close?

Comment: @Martheen That would be preferred, but I wouldn't say it's a requirement

Comment: Afaik there's no api for it.  Easy to fake however: make a screenshot of the desktop, darken it and display it in your own full-screen borderless window.  Do pause a bit at the user's response to UI that doesn't do what they are used to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've built a mini library that you can use, please see the [github repo](https://github.com/DeanVanGreunen/SmartScreenDialogLibrary)

Example Popup

[image]

call it like such

```cs
using SmartScreenMessagePopupDialog;

SmartScreenMessageDialog customWindow = new SmartScreenMessageDialog("Welcome", "Hi there, this is an example", true);
customWindow.Show();
```

#### info (repo info)

- library in `SmartScreenMessagePopupDialog`
- test app in `ConsoleApp1`

## Source

if you dont want the whole project here is the source for the dialog

you do need the `System.Drawing.dll` and `System.Windows.Forms.dll`

```cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement.Window;

namespace SmartScreenMessagePopupDialog
{
    public class SmartScreenMessageDialog
    {
        private Form customForm;
        private string mTitle;
        private string mMessage;
        private Boolean mShowOkayButton;

        public SmartScreenMessageDialog(string title, string message, Boolean showOkayButton = true)
        {
            Screen primaryScreen = Screen.PrimaryScreen;
            int screenWidth = primaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
            int screenHeight = primaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
            this.mTitle = title;
            this.mMessage = message;
            this.mShowOkayButton = showOkayButton;
            customForm = new Form();
            customForm.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0x01, 0x67, 0xB2);
            customForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            customForm.Text = this.mTitle;
            customForm.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 360);
            int centerX = ((screenWidth / 2) - (customForm.Size.Width / 2));
            int centerY = ((screenHeight / 2) - (customForm.Size.Height / 2));
            customForm.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(centerX, centerY);

            Label myTitle = new Label();
            myTitle.Text = this.mTitle;
            myTitle.Location = new Point(32, 32);
            myTitle.ForeColor = Color.White;
            myTitle.Size = new Size(customForm.Size.Width - 32, 64);
            myTitle.Font = new Font(myTitle.Font.FontFamily, 22, FontStyle.Bold);
            customForm.Controls.Add(myTitle);

            Label myMessage = new Label();
            myMessage.Text = this.mMessage;
            myMessage.Location = new Point(32, myTitle.Size.Height + 32);
            myMessage.ForeColor = Color.White;
            myMessage.Size = new Size(customForm.Size.Width - 32, 200);
            myMessage.Font = new Font(myMessage.Font.FontFamily, 12, FontStyle.Regular);
            customForm.Controls.Add(myMessage);

            if (showOkayButton)
            {
                Button closeButton = new Button();
                closeButton.Text = "Okay";
                closeButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 32);
                int xFactor = 32;
                int yFactor = 32;
                closeButton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                closeButton.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 1;
                closeButton.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.White;
                closeButton.ForeColor = Color.White;
                closeButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(customForm.Size.Width - (closeButton.Size.Width + xFactor), customForm.Size.Height - (closeButton.Size.Height + yFactor));
                closeButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    customForm.Close();
                };
                customForm.Controls.Add(closeButton);
            }
        }

        public void Show()
        {
            this.customForm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe they just want the "design" of the message, not an actual shutdown prompt. This kind of message box appears for SmartScreen and other stuff as well, so this might be a possible?

Comment: Just like @RedyAu mentioned, I don't want to shutdown, only use the message itself without shutting down. Clarified the question!

Comment: @Jonathan see my edited answer, here is what you are looking for, you can fork and customize my library as you wish. this should get you on track and heading in a good direction, good luck

Comment: @Jonathan if this is what you're looking for, please don't forget to mark it as the answer, i'm here to help and do it for the points.

Comment: I was trying to see if it was possible to use the built-in message but seems like that's not possible. I had already made a "clone" in winforms but wondered about the possibilities of using the builtin one. Thanks!